# Changing the “VerifyEmail” class for custom parameter in verification link in mail for method verificationUrl() in verification email in laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, email-verification, laravel-5.7

verification email that come with laravel 5.7. How and where i need to change it? I had searched all over online, but because it is brand new feature in 5.7,So i could not find an answer. Can you help me please? Thanks in advance.

basically that class is under Illuminate\Auth\Notifications

i want to override one of the method:

```
 class VerifyEmail extends Notification
        {
          // i wish i could override this method
           protected function verificationUrl($notifiable)
            {
             return URL::temporarySignedRoute('verification.verify', Carbon::now()->addMinutes(60), ['id' => $notifiable->getKey()]);
            } 
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because your `User` Model uses `Illuminate\Auth\MustVerifyEmail` you can override the method [`sendEmailVerificationNotification`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/a168181f8188a4e6cd7d3f87b4f8f29a080172aa/src/Illuminate/Auth/MustVerifyEmail.php#L34) which is the method that notifies the created user by calling the method `notify` and passes, as a parameter, a new instance of the `Notifications\MustVerifyEmail` class.

You can create a custom Notification which will be passed as parameter to `$this->notify()` within the `sendEmailVerificationNotification` method in your `User` Model:

```
public function sendEmailVerificationNotification()
{
    $this->notify(new App\Notifications\CustomVerifyEmail);
}
```

And in your `CustomVerifyEmail` Notification you can define the `route` through which the verification will be handled and all parameters that it will take.

When a new user signs up an `Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered` Event is emitted in the `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController` and that event has a listener `Illuminate\Auth\Listeners\SendEmailVerificationNotification` which is registered in the `App\Providers\EventServiceProvider`:

```
protected $listen = [
    Registered::class => [
        SendEmailVerificationNotification::class,
    ]
];
```

This listener checks if the `$user`, which is passed as a parameter to `new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all()))` in the Laravel default authentication `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController`, is an instance of `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail` which is the trait that Laravel suggest to use in the `App\User` Model when you want to provide default email verification and check also that `$user` is not already verified. If all that passes it will call the `sendEmailVerificationNotification` method on that user:

```
if ($event->user instanceof MustVerifyEmail && !$event->user->hasVerifiedEmail()) {
        $event->user->sendEmailVerificationNotification();
}
```

Comment: working fine! after doing above changes for custom email verification @YvesKipondo